# A four quadrant floating point inverse tangent function

Tags: latex3, floating-point

After a chat discussion yesterday, I decided to write an inverse tangent function that normalizes the angle in the range [0,2\pi] (or [0,360] in degrees of course). Doing so was easy. My question is, is there a better way to do this, short of adding it natively to LaTeX3, so that it can be evaluated in with `\fp_eval:n` as, for example,

`\fp_eval:n { atannorm(0.5,sqrt(3)/2)}`?

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \joe_atannormd:n {%
  % create and set a temporary list to #1
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 } 
  % need to extract the first argument
  \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 } }
  % normalize to [0,360] if the first argument < 0
  \fp_eval:n { \fp_compare_p:n { \l_tmpa_fp < 0 }  ? atand(#1) + 360 : atand(#1) } 
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\atannormd}{ r() }{%
  \joe_atannormd:n { #1 }
}%

\cs_new_protected:Nn \joe_atannorm:n {%
  % create and set a temporary list to #1
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 } 
  % need to extract the first argument
  \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 } }
  % normalize to [0,2pi] if the first argument < 0
  \fp_eval:n { \fp_compare_p:n { \l_tmpa_fp < 0 }  ? atan(#1) + 2*pi : atan(#1) } 
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\atannorm}{ r() }{%
  \joe_atannorm:n { #1 }
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Normalized to \( 2\pi \):

\( \atannorm(0,1) \)

\( \atannorm(1,1) \)

\( \atannorm(1,0) \)

\( \atannorm(1,-1) \)

\( \atannorm(0,-1) \)

\( \atannorm(-1,-1) \)

\( \atannorm(-1,0) \)

Normalized to \( 360^\circ \):

\( \atannormd(0,1)^\circ \)

\( \atannormd(1,1)^\circ \)

\( \atannormd(1,0)^\circ \)

\( \atannormd(1,-1)^\circ \)

\( \atannormd(0,-1)^\circ \)

\( \atannormd(-1,-1)^\circ \)

\( \atannormd(-1,0)^\circ \)

\( \atannormd(0.5,sqrt(3)/2)^\circ \)

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: atan2(y,x) performs that function.  I assume the y come first to match atan(y/x).

Comment: The standard `atan2(y,x)` returns angles normalized to [0,pi] and [0,-pi]. I tested `LaTeX3`'s `atan()` function and it did the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define `atannorm` as a “fp word”, so `\fp_eval:n { atannorm(#1,#2) }` would work, but that requires using `l3fp` internals, so that's not a good idea.  At the cost of one backslash more in the function call you can define an expandable `\atannorm` with a required argument delimited by `()`:

```latex
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \atannorm { r() }
  { \joe_atannorm:nnn {#1} { atan } { 2*pi } }
```

(the second and third arguments are so that you can define both `\atannorm` and `\atannormd` in terms of the same internal)
then split at the comma:

```latex
\cs_new:Npn \joe_atannorm:nnn #1
  { \__joe_atannorm:wwnn #1 \scan_stop: }
```

and pass that to a macro that puts everything together:

```latex
\cs_new:Npn \__joe_atannorm:wwnn #1 , #2 \scan_stop: #3 #4
  { \use:e { ( #3 (#1,#2) \fp_compare:nNnT {#1} < { 0 } { + #4 } ) } }
```

The code does not check if the input does in fact contain a `,` and will throw a low-level error if it does not (it's rather easy to add if needed).  The `\use:e` trick is there because `l3fp` expands step by step, which can be rather slow, so the `\use:e` is there to speed things up a bit.  An extra set of parenthesis is added so that, say, `\atannorm(-1,-1)*2` works as expected.

Here is the full code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \atannorm { r() }
  { \joe_atannorm:nnn {#1} { atan } { 2*pi } }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \atannormd { r() }
  { \joe_atannorm:nnn {#1} { atand } { 360 } }
\cs_new:Npn \joe_atannorm:nnn #1
  { \__joe_atannorm:wwnn #1 \scan_stop: }
\cs_new:Npn \__joe_atannorm:wwnn #1 , #2 \scan_stop: #3 #4
  { \use:e { ( #3 (#1,#2) \fp_compare:nNnT {#1} < { 0 } { + #4 } ) } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Normalized to \( 2\pi \):

\( \fpeval{ \atannorm (0,1) } \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannorm (1,1) } \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannorm (1,0) } \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannorm (1,-1) } \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannorm (0,-1) } \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannorm (-1,-1) } \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannorm (-1,0) } \)

Normalized to \( 360^\circ \):

\( \fpeval{ \atannormd (0,1) }^\circ \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannormd (1,1) }^\circ \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannormd (1,0) }^\circ \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannormd (1,-1) }^\circ \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannormd (0,-1) }^\circ \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannormd (-1,-1) }^\circ \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannormd (-1,0) }^\circ \)

\( \fpeval{ \atannormd (0.5,sqrt(3)/2) }^\circ \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: I looked at the source code last night and saw how the "fp word" is defined. I also toyed with an expandable command, but don't recall why I didn't include it here. Let me study this solution.